# Cygwin installer does not terminate if run as administrator

Tags: windows, installation, cygwin, silent-install

I want to install Cygwin quietly. The problem is, that the setup does not terminate. It stays open in the background and takes 100% CPU usage. This can be seen in the task manager.

I am calling the setup like this:

```
setup-x86.exe -q -P rsync -R C:\smo-cygwin
```

These are the meanings of the flags:

```
-q is quiet
"-P rsync" means install rsync package
"-R C:\smo-cygwin" changes the destination install path
```

The log file (C:\smo-cygwin\var\log\setup.log) is about 12GiB after 5min and it looks like this:

```
...
2021/11/29 13:21:38 Changing gid back to original
...
2021/11/29 13:22:05 running: C:\smo-cygwin\bin\dash.exe "/etc/postinstall/zp_man-db-update-index.dash"
2021/11/29 13:22:05 Changing gid to AdministratorsEnding cygwin install
...
```

The line "Changing gid to AdministratorsEnding cygwin install" then appears millions of times. It never ends and there are no other log lines coming.

Is this a bug?

**Edit**:

I now found out it only happens if I run the setup as administrator.
Please note I am using the x86 installer under Windows 10 64bit.
And not the x86_64 installer. I am choosing the x86 installer for compatibility reasons (I am developing a portable backup program).

Comment: If it already exists, try deleting the contents of `[cygwin_install_dir]\var\log` before running the installer. Also, check if one of these pieces of software is installed https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda

Comment: I have deleted all logs and there is almost no software installed on the machine. Still not working..

Comment: It works for me. Any indication inside `/var/log/setup.log.full` ?

Comment: It seems to me that the problem doesn't always occur. The setup.log is 16MiB big and there is always the same line thousands of time. See my edit.

Comment: Have you tried running the setup with administrator rights?

Comment: `Changing gid to Administrators` should be reported only one time.

Comment: It only happens if I run the setup as administrator. Also I provided a log in the edit.